# Slick Slider slide overflow issue

Tags: css, slick.js

I am trying to scale my slides on hover. But if i enable the overflow of the wrapper, it overflows in x-axis as well, i only want it to overflow vertically.
Please see the codepen: http://codepen.io/faranali9/pen/qRPXGq

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container slider">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae eligendi ipsum molestiae nam voluptatum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
  padding:0 30px;
}

img{
  max-width:100%;
}
.slide{
  transition:all 0.3s;
  transform-origin:center;
}

.slide:hover{
  transform:scale(1.3);
}

.description{
  display:none;
}
.slide:hover .description{
  display:block;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.slider').slick(
{
  slidesToShow:5,
  arrows:true
});
```

Comment: Have you tried just using transform:scaleX() or transform:scaleY() on your hover event?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be scaling the `img` instead of the `.slide`. I also added some padding to the `.slide` to accommodate the top overflow.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/egGyKw

Comment: Thanks but I cannot add padding in my scenario.. I need it to grow out and overflow.
And I dont want the wrapper to resize in height on hover ( see the next button go down when hovering over image)